# what is the right way to find the child nodes of an element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am selecting a div with container class. But If I  want to find the child nodes of this element, it says undefined.

```js
let targetNode=document.getElementsByClassName('container')
console.log(targetNode.childNodes)
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, assumenda.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]` since [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a `HTMLCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let targetNode=document.getElementsByClassName('container')
console.log(targetNode[0].childNodes)
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, assumenda.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.document.getElementsByClassName('container')` will return a collection of HTMLElements.
So all you have to do is specify which element you want to access with an index like this:

```
var children = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var child;
if (children != undefined && children.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0 ; i < children.length; i++) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('container')[i])
  }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I just want to see all my nodes in this particular div

Comment: in the console? You could loop over them. Ive updated my answer